# C#: Custom Control with ControlDesigner, using in other Project with Client Profile

Tags: c#, custom-controls, .net-client-profile

I wrote a CustomControl with ControlDesigner for Design-Time interaction.
All works fine, but how can i release the custom control, to use it in other Projects with Client Profile Framework?

I can add the Control to other Projects (with Client Profile) and do everthing until I try to Debug the Project.
After debuging the project doesn't find the Control anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching i have fond the not realy sweet solution: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WinFormsCustomCtrl